# GroupBy Select with String.Join

Tags: c#, linq

I have a line that looks like this:

```
var activeEquipList = issued.Union(request).GroupBy(x=>x.EquipID).Select(x=>new EquipList()
{
    EquipCount = x.Count(),
    EquipName = db.tblMasterEquipLists.Find(x.Key).Equipment,
    Serial = x.Where(t => t.EquipID == x.Key).ToArray().Select(g=>g.Serial.Join(",",)) // problem line
}).ToList();
```

**Explanation**

`Serial` is of type `string`.  There can be many of the same objects, but each object has a different serial number.  This program has already been written, and I don't want to change the type of `Serial` to `List<string>`, so I was thinking I could **join** all of the different serial numbers for the same pieces of equipment, and separate them by a comma.

How can I achieve this?  Or, if this cannot be achieved then, what is a better approach?  If I have to change the type of `Serial` then I am open to that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do following:

```
Serial = string.Join(",", x.Where(t => t.EquipID == x.Key).Select(g => g.Serial))
```

Comment: Thank you!  I do need the `Where` clause in mine, so thank you! I will accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, one more sip of coffee and I figured it out:

```
var activeEquipList = issued.Union(request).GroupBy(x=>x.EquipID).Select(x=>new EquipList()
{
    EquipCount = x.Count(),
    EquipName = db.tblMasterEquipLists.Find(x.Key).Equipment,
    Serial = string.Join(", ", x.Select(t => t.Serial)
}).ToList();
```